# Pass navigation variables to router in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I'm trying to pass in variables through the navigation bar for my router.

I'm using Node.js with express and mongolab for the database for this.

Here is the working code:

```
router.get('/sort/50/time', function(req, res) {
   var db = req.db;
   var collection = db.get('twots');
   collection.find({},{'skip':0, 'limit':50, 'sort':{_id: -1}},function(e,docs){
   res.json(docs);
   });
});
```

It gives me a database list from mongolab.

But I want to do something like this:

```
router.get('/sort:VARIABLE2:VARIABLE1', function(req, res) {
   var db = req.db;
   var collection = db.get('twots');
   collection.find({},{'skip':0, 'limit':req.params.VARIABLE2, 'sort':{req.params.VARIABLE1: -1}},function(e,docs){
   res.json(docs);
   });
});
```

This doesn't work, and can't find the correct code for this. (it can't find req.params.VARIABLE1 or VARIABLE2)
Right now I've coded the hard way, using no variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to include the slashes:

```
router.get('/sort/:VARIABLE2/:VARIABLE1', function(req, res) { ... })
```